# Easiest way to calculate time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time, while-loop, code-analysis

I find it pretty easy to calculate the time complexity for most problems, but my prof gives really complicated examples and I have trouble figuring them out. Here are two that he's given us that I couldn't get to the bottom of:

**Example 1:**

```
x = 0
j = n
while (j >= 1)
    for i = 1 to j do
        x += 1
    j *= 3/4
return x
```

**Example2:**

```
x = 0
j = 3
while (j <= n)
    x += 1
    j *= j
return x
```

*Please note that for operations like **x += 1** and **j *= j**, we only count this as 1 time unit.*

If you could show me how you would calculate the time complexity for these examples, I should be able to deduce how I would do it for most of the ones he gives. Thanks!

Comment: What is initial value of `j` in 1st example?

Comment: This is not in any way my field of expertise but you could draw these on a graph for yourself. x=j, y = iterations for given j value. the 2nd one is O(sqrt(n)) btw, because of the j*=j. The first one... O(n^x) from how i see. But i could be wrong.

Comment: @vish4071 my mistake! I made the change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers:

```
1. O(j)
2. O(log log(n))
```

Explanation:

1. See the inner loop. It operates `j` times in the 1st entry. Now, `j=3j/4`. So, second time, it operates `3j/4` times. 3rd time, `9j/16`, and so on. The total number of operations will be:

   j + 3j/4 + 9j/16 + ...
   = 4j

So, complexity will be O(4*j) = O(j).

2. There is only one loop. The value of its controller (j) increases as:

   3, 9, 81, 6561, ...

Now, the number of iterations it will make until it reaches a certain number `n` will be log log (n). If it increased by a multiple of 3 everytime, like:

```
3, 9, 27, 81, 243...
```

the complexity would have been O(log n).

Comment: Sorry, it seems I made a mistake with the first question. I added what j is initially set to

Comment: If `j=n`, complexity in 1st case is `O(n)`, that's it.

Comment: I figured. Sorry, I didn't get the chance to look at your answer until now!

Comment: Might I inquire as to what the first one would be if it didn't have the inner loop?

Comment: O(log n), and the base of this `log` would have been 4/3 (not 2, as is with most log-complex algorithms). Not that it matters when we are writing `complexity`.